Late 90’s Gross-out Comedy Sport Movie
I’m looking for the name of a US comedy movie of the “Gross-out” variety.
It was produced around the end of the 1990s and the basis was a couple of friends who invent their own version of a sport which then takes off in a big way.
The premise was that although they were good at one particular aspect of the sport they weren’t good enough to beat regular players but when taking on a couple of people they pretend that they were playing their version and make up the rules as they go
The rules involve doing anything to distract their opponents up to but not including (I think) touching them. Their ability to gross out their opponents or otherwise fake then out leads to them winning (naturally).
As I recall, the new version took off and eventually led to leagues and championships being created and there were shenanigans involved there too.
There were two or three principal friends / protagonists early/mid 20s , young caucasian men if I remember correctly.
Anyone know this movie?

It’s not Dodgeball although it had a similar vibe.

This is BASEketball (1998) with Trey Parket & Matt Stone (of South Park fame) and was a typical David Zucker movie.



Wikipedia

Coop (Trey Parker) and Remer (Matt Stone) are 23 and unemployed. They arrive uninvited at a party hosted by a former high school classmate. After finding that their classmates have matured, Coop and Remer find themselves outside drinking beer and shooting hoops. Two former classmates challenge them to a game. The two see that their opponents are very good at basketball, so they say they will only play a new game they picked up while secretly inventing the rules as they go along and winning the new game.
Six months later, Businessman Ted Denslow (Ernest Borgnine) shows up to propose the creation of the National BASEketball League (NBL), with numerous rules in place to prevent the sport from deteriorating as other sports had done: teams cannot switch cities, players cannot be traded, and individuals cannot make money via corporate sponsorship deals.
Five years after creation of the league, the NBL is in full swing with stadiums, teams, fans, and a major championship (the Denslow Cup).


